Implementing an architecture from research paper
I am trying to implement a research paper from scratch. I need to know if what I am doing is on the correct path and whether there are any improvements that I can do.
This is what I have implemented. However I am not sure whether so far this is correct or not.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchsummary import summary

# This is the implementation of a single block of the Pyramid Dilated Convolutional Block
class _PyramidDilatedConvBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, dilation_rates):
        super(_PyramidDilatedConvBlock, self).__init__()
        
        # This is the parallel convolutional block
        self.parallel_conv_blocks = nn.ModuleList([
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, dilation=d, padding=d) for d in dilation_rates
        ])
        # Here we concat the output of the paralle convolutional block and pass it through a 1x1 convolutional block
        # followed by a batch normalization layer, a max pooling layer and a ReLU activation function.
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(len(dilation_rates) * out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        features = [conv(x) for conv in self.parallel_conv_blocks]
        return self.conv(torch.cat(features, dim=1))

class PDD_UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=1, out_channels=1, features=[16, 32, 64, 128, 256], dilation_rates=[1, 2, 3, 4]):
        super(PDD_UNet, self).__init__()
        # This if for the downsampling path
        self.downs = nn.ModuleList()
        # This is for the upsampling path
        self.up_lists = nn.ModuleList()

        # This is the first path of the downsampling path
        # Based on the number of features, we will create downsampling blocks
        for feature in features:
            self.downs.append(_PyramidDilatedConvBlock(in_channels, feature, dilation_rates))
            in_channels = feature

        # For every downsampling block, we will create an upsampling block            
        for i in range(len(self.downs)):
            block_index = i - 1
            up_list = nn.ModuleList()
            for _ in range(block_index):
                # The upsampled output is then processed by the PyramidDilatedConvBlock
                # after concatenating the output of skip connection
                up_list.append(_PyramidDilatedConvBlock(
                                in_channels=features[block_index],
                                out_channels=features[block_index+1],
                                dilation_rates=dilation_rates
                                ))

            self.up_lists.append(up_list)

    def forward(self, x):
        skip_connections = []
        to_upsample_connections = []
        up_skip_connections = []

        # Since the first block does not have upsampled block,
        # we will not append it to the to_upsample
        x = self.downs[0](x)
        skip_connections.append(x)

        # This is the downsampling path        
        for down in self.downs[1:-1]:
            x = down(x)
            skip_connections.append(x)
            to_upsample_connections.append(x)
        
        # Since last block is not followed by a skip connection,
        # we will not append it to the skip connections
        x = self.downs[-1](x)
        to_upsample_connections.append(x)

        # This is the upsampling path
        for to_upsample_connection, up_list, deafult_skip_connection in zip(to_upsample_connections, self.up_lists, skip_connections):
            skip_connection = None
            for up in up_list:
                # The output of the downsampling block is first upsampled
                to_upsample_connection = nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                    in_channels=to_upsample_connection.size(1),
                    out_channels=to_upsample_connection.size(1),
                    kernel_size=2,
                    stride=2
                )(to_upsample_connection)
                
                # The output of the skip connection is then processed by a 1x1 convolutional block
                # to make the channels same as upsampled output and concatenated with the upsampled output
                deafult_skip_connection = nn.Conv2d(deafult_skip_connection.size(1), to_upsample_connection.size(1), kernel_size=1)(deafult_skip_connection)
                if up_list.index(up) > 0:
                    skip_connection = up_skip_connections.reverse().pop()
                
                if skip_connection is not None:
                    to_upsample_connection = torch.cat([deafult_skip_connection, skip_connection, to_upsample_connection], dim=1)
                    skip_connection = None
                else:
                    to_upsample_connection = torch.cat([deafult_skip_connection, to_upsample_connection], dim=1)

                # The concatenated output is then passed through the PyramidDilatedConvBlock
                to_upsample_connection = up(to_upsample_connection)
                    
                # This is another skip connection forming a pyramid
                up_skip_connections.append(to_upsample_connection)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    # Model instantiation
    model = PDD_UNet().to(device)
    # print(model)
    summary(model, (1, 256, 256))

I am still in progress of implementation and would be very happy for some inputs to my implementation.

Since there isn't a specific question here, this is more suited for Code Review SE.
